# Combining jquery for effiency

Tags: jquery

Attempting to condense some of the coding on a website I'm now looking after and was wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing the following coding as I realise there is doubling up of information.

```
$("span.menu-link-title.active-components").mouseover(function(){$('#active-components-image').css('display', 'block');});
$("span.menu-link-title.active-components").mouseleave(function(){$('#active-components-image').css('display', 'none');});
$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").mouseover(function(){$('#adaptors-image').css('display', 'block');});
$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").mouseleave(function(){$('#adaptors-image').css('display', 'none');});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hover` and `toggle` methods:

```
$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").hover(function(){
   $('#adaptors-image').toggle();
});
```

`hover` is a shorthand for `mouseenter`(*not mouseover*) and `mouseleave` events and it also accepts 2 functions. You can also cache the objects.

```
var $adapt = $('#adaptors-image');
$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").hover(function(){
    $adap.show(); // mouseenter
}, function(){
    $adap.hide(); // mouseleave
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a little more lean:

```
$("span.menu-link-title.active-components").hover(function() {
    $('#active-components-image').toggle();
});
$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").hover(function() {
    $('#adaptors-image').toggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Most jQuery methods return the object, allowing you to chain events:

```
$("span.menu-link-title.active-components").mouseover(function(){
    $('#active-components-image').css('display', 'block');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#active-components-image').css('display', 'none');
});

$("span.menu-link-title.adaptors").mouseover(function(){
    $('#adaptors-image').css('display', 'block');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#adaptors-image').css('display', 'none');
});
```

You can create chains like this as long as you'd like.

See [this article](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging chaining and end method, you can write as

```
$("span.menu-link-title").find(".adaptors").hover(function(){
   $('#adaptors-image').toggle();
}).end().find(".active-components").hover(function(){
   $('#active-components-image').toggle();  
});
```